# программа по обработке строк

Tags: c++, qt, строки, qstring

Вобщем есть код программы из приложения QT widgets, которая обрабатывает строки. А я хочу ее запустить в консольном приложении, но что-то пока не особо получается.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std; 
 
const QString separators = "\n !@:?#$%^&*()_+{}\\|/,.!-";
bool isSeparator(QChar ch)
{
    return separators.contains(ch);
}
 
const QString digits = "0123456789";
bool isNumeric(QChar ch)
{
    return digits.contains(ch);
}
 
string reverse_content(const char* charstr)
{
    string result="";
    for (int i=strlen(charstr)-1;i>=0;i--)
        result+=charstr[i];
    return result;
}
 
 
QString processLine(QString line, bool rev)
{
    QString word("");
    QString new_line("");
    QString result("");
    QChar prev_c('\n');
 
    int len = line.length();
 
    for (int i=0;i<=len;i++)
    {
        QChar c= i<len? line.at(i):'\n';
        if (isSeparator(c))
        {
            if (c==' ' && ((word.length()==0 && new_line.length()==0) || prev_c==' '))
            {
                // пробелы в начале или несколько пробелов между словами - ничего не делаем
            } else
            if (c=='-' && i+1!=len && isNumeric(line.at(i+1)))
            {
                // это число со знаком минус
                word+=c;
            } else
            {
                if (word.length()>0)
                {
                    if (rev)
                    {
                        std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
                        //word = reverse_content(word.c_str());
                    }
                new_line+=word;
                }
                if (c=='.' && prev_c == ' ')
                {
                    // нужно удалить пробел перед точкой
                    new_line = new_line.left(new_line.length()-1);
                }
                if (c!='\n') new_line+=c;
                if (c=='.' || c=='\n')
                {
                    if (new_line.length()>0 && new_line!=".") result += (new_line+'\n');
                    new_line="";
                    word="";
                }
                word = "";
            }
        } else word+=c;
        prev_c = c;
    }
    if (new_line.length()>0)   result += new_line;
 
    return result;
}
int main(){
 
        string input = "input.txt";
        string output1 = "output.txt";
        string output2 = "output2.txt";
    int res=processLine(input,output1,false);
    if (res){
 
        cout << input <<" to "<< output1 <<" - OK\n";
    }
    else{
 
        cout<< input << " to "<< output1 <<" - ERROR\n";
        return 0;
    }
    res=processLine(output1,output2,true);
    cout << output1 <<" to "<< output2 <<" - "<< (res?"OK\n":"ERROR\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Через это поппробовала
ifstream ifile("input.txt");
ofstream ofile("output.txt");
Хотя подозрения, что дело совсем не в этом, не особо понимаю что делать

Comment: Опишите в чем проблема

Comment: Возникает ошибка could not convert 'output1' from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'QString'
     res=processLine(output1,output2,true);

Comment: А что вам не понятно в этой ошибке?

Comment: как ее исправить

Comment: ну вот подумайте сами: у вас проблема в том, что вы передаёте std::string в то время как ожидается QString - о чем вам и сообщает компилятор. Как ее исправить? Очень просто - использовать QString вместо std::string.

Comment: я не вижу где использовать в том то и прикол

Comment: вы сами написали вышеприведенных код?

Comment: В том то и дело, что нет

Comment: исправляла на QString input = "input.txt";
        QString output1 = "output.txt";
        QString output2 = "output2.txt"; Но вылазят ошибки  cannot convert 'QString' to 'bool' for argument '2' to 'QString processLine(QString, bool)'
     int res=processLine(input,output1,false); и  cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
         cout << input <<" to "<< output1 << " - OK\n";

Comment: а может лучше начать язык изучать? Вы не сможете писать код, если элементарно языка не знаете

Comment: А почему бы ее просто не переписать *без* QT? Это несложно :) Да и сам вопрос вами задан неверно. Если вы даже ухитритесь методом тыка заставить код компилироваться - это не гарантия верной работы и уж наверняка не приведет к пониманию, как быть в следующий раз и вообще - к пониманию...

Comment: @АлександраГребнева получилось по решению ниже?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде я разобрался в этом и сделал, но тому, кто писал код (в вопросе) - очень советую почитать про форматирование кода.

Также не совсем понятно чего вы пытались добиться этим:

```
int res=processLine(input,output1,false);
```

Вы вызываете функцию, принимающую **два** аргумента, а передаёте ей **три**, а потом ещё и пытаетесь возвращаемое значения типа `string` присвоить переменой типа `int` (`int` тип данных для целых **чисел**). Почитайте про типы данных и поймёте, что далеко не всё можно положить в `int`.

Сделал я без фишек QT вроде `QString` или `QChar`. В `main` вызывается функция обработки текста, результат записывается в файл `output.txt`. Вы пытались прочитать файл, вызывая функцию обработки, и имея только название файла (но не сам файл), а потом результат положить в переменную `int` и ждали, что в файле `output.txt`, которого опять же нет (только имя) окажется текст. Эта функция не читает и не записывает ничего в файл. И тем, что вы дадите ей имена нужных вам файлов - вы ничего не добьётесь. Она просто обработает имена и вернёт их. И вообще, лучше, как сказал *Andrej Levkovitch* сначала учите язык, а потом уже пишите код.

Также в файл `ouput2.txt` записывается тот же обработанный текст, но наоборот.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const string separators = "\n !@:?#$%^&*()_+{}\\|/,.!-";
bool isSeparator(char ch)
{
    return separators.find(ch) != string::npos;
}

const string digits = "0123456789";
bool isNumeric(char ch)
{
    return digits.find(ch) != string::npos;
}

string reverse(const char* charstr)
{
    string result="";
    for (int i = sizeof(charstr) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        result += charstr[i];
    return result;
}

string processLine(string line, bool rev)
{
    string word(""), new_line(""), result("");
    char prev_c('\n'), c;

    unsigned long long len = line.length();

    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i <= len; ++i) {
        c = i < len ? line.at(i) : '\n';

        if (isSeparator(c)) {
            if (isspace(c) && ((word.length() == 0 && new_line.length() == 0) || isspace(prev_c))) {
                // пробелы в начале или несколько пробелов между словами - ничего не делаем
            }
            else {
                if (c == '-' && i + 1 != len && isNumeric(line.at(i+1))) {
                    // это число со знаком минус
                    word += c;
                }
                else {
                    if (word.length() > 0) {
                        if (rev) {
                            //std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
                            word = reverse(word.c_str());
                        }
                        new_line += word;
                    }
                    if (c == '.' && isspace(prev_c)) {
                        // нужно удалить пробел перед точкой
                        new_line.erase(i - 1, 1);
                    }
                    if (c != '\n') new_line += c;
                    if (c == '.' || c == '\n') {
                        if (new_line.length()>0 && new_line!=".") result += (new_line+'\n');
                        new_line="";
                        word="";
                    }
                word = "";
                }
            }
        }
        else word += c;
        prev_c = c;
    }
    if (new_line.length() > 0) result += new_line;

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    string input = "input.txt";
    string output = "output.txt";
    string output_2 = "output2.txt";

    ifstream file(input);
    if (!file.is_open()){
        cout << "Error while opening the input file.";
        return 1;
    }

    ofstream out_file(output);
    if (!out_file.is_open()){
        cout << "Error while opening the output file.";
        file.close();
        return 1;
    }

    ofstream out_file2(output_2);
    if (!out_file2.is_open()){
        cout << "Error while opening the output 2 file.";
        file.close();
        out_file.close();
        return 1;
    }

    string tmp = "", res;
    while(getline(file, tmp)){
        res = processLine(tmp, false);
        out_file << res;

        res = processLine(tmp, true);
        out_file2 << res;
    }

    out_file.close();
    out_file2.close();
    file.close();

    cout << "Programm finished successfully";
    return 0;
}
```